# How to set multiple "setwhatIds" and "setTargetObjectIds" in salesforce?

Tags: email, email-template, apex-email-service, email-alert, massemailmessage

How can I set multiple objects Id in targetObjectsIds and WhatIds?? Whenver I tried to do that it gives an error

```
String[] bccAddress = new String[] {'contact@testcompany.com'};

Messaging.MassEmailMessage CPMail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();

CPMail.setTargetObjectIds(emailRecipientsList);

CPMail.setBccAddresses(bccAddress);

CPMail.setTemplateId(EmailTemplate.Id);

CPMail.setSenderDisplayName('surgaya');

CPMail.setUseSignature(false);

CPMail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
```

Can we use setTemplateId along with setHtmlBody of a template ?

Below is my sendEmail function in utilityClass which send multiple emails :

```
String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HtmlValue; 
mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
mail.setPlainTextBody(plainBody); 
listSingleEmailMessages.add(mail); }
listEmailResult = Messaging.sendEmail(listSingleEmailMessages);
```

Comment: and the error message is ...?

Comment: Can we use setTemplateId along with setHtmlBody of a template ?
Below is my sendEmail function in utilityClass which send multiple emails :
   
 String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HtmlValue;
 mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody); 
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
mail.setPlainTextBody(plainBody);     
listSingleEmailMessages.add(mail);  }listEmailResult = Messaging.sendEmail(listSingleEmailMessages);

Comment: Surgaya -- what you have posted is a bit incomplete - 1) like what is the value inside of `emailRecipientsList` ? 2) The Utility method is incomplete - no signature, missing {, 3) you never identified the error you got. I've found that these types of problems are best resolved using anonymous apex wherein you get something working (like one email in the mass email) and successively add in bits to see where the issue is. You will not be helped by the fact that the SFDC Apex Email messaging doc is incomplete and in places, wrong.